# Combine to columns into one new column in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have problem merging 2 columns into single column in mySQL.

this what i want to happen:

from this

```
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    male        |     female     |   gender |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    male        |      null      |   null   |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    male        |      null      |   null   |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    null        |    female      |   null   |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
|    male        |      null      |   null   |
+----------------+----------------+----------+
```

to this

```
+----------+
|   gender |
+----------+
|   male   |
+----------+
|   male   |
+----------+
|  female  |
+----------+
|   male   |
+----------+
```

I have used:

```
SELECT male, 
   female, 
   COALESCE(male, female) AS gender 
FROM nrco_ldap
```

but nothing happens in the gender column.

Comment: can you paste your output? because I can get the right result.

Comment: i have to combine male and female columns and move it to the gender column.

Comment: @ChrisChan I don't think you can do that if the gender column already exist. I recommend you take out the gender row first, before trying again.

Comment: @shree i already have a gender column with no values in it.

Comment: @steve it says its ok but whenever i view the gender column its empty.

Comment: @frosty i will try that i hope that works

Comment: @ChrisChan Are you saying that male, female and gender are not column names?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to **update** an existing column, so a `select` is clearly not the way to do it. Therefore, you need to write an `update` query like so:

```
update nrco_ldap
set gender = coalesce(male,female)
```

If in addition to populating the `gender` column, you want to delete the `male` and `female` columns, you will need to write the appropriate drop statements like so:

```
alter table nrco_ldap drop column male;
alter table nrco_ldap drop column female;
```